# Considering the linear system $Y'=AY$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What would be an equation that I can use when I compute the eigenpairs for the coefficient matrix $A.$

Comment: $AX=\lambda X$?

Comment: Would I need to find the det of A

Comment: oh is that where I would subtract the lambda from a and d?

Comment: If you're talking about $2\times 2$ matrices with $a,d$ on the diagonal, yes.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more specific. Thank you!

Comment: To take @julien's answer one step further, note that $AX=\lambda X$ is equivalent to $AX - \lambda X = 0$, which simplifies to $(A-\lambda I)X = 0$, which requires $det(A-\lambda I)=0$ if you want $X \neq 0$...

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the fundamental idea for solving a system of linear ode's with constant coefficients.

To solve the system $Y'(t)=AY(t)$, assuming for simplicity $A_{2\times 2}$ matrix, we assume the solution to have the form

> $$ Y(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
>   k_1 \\
>   k_2
> \end{bmatrix}\rm e^{\lambda t} \implies Y'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
>   k_1 \\
>   k_2
> \end{bmatrix}\lambda \rm e^{\lambda t}. $$

Now, we substitute back in the Diff. eq. which gives

> $$ Y'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
>   k_1 \\
>   k_2
> \end{bmatrix}\lambda \rm e^{\lambda t} = A \begin{bmatrix}
>   k_1 \\
>   k_2
> \end{bmatrix}\rm e^{\lambda t}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
>  \lambda k_1 \\
>  \lambda k_2
> \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
>  a & b \\
>  c & d
> \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
>  k_1 \\
>  k_2
> \end{bmatrix}. $$

Solve the last system for $k_1$ and $k_2$. In order to get a non trivial solution for the system we force the determinant of the matrix of the coefficients to be zero which results in getting $\lambda's$ the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

In the two dimensional case, the eigenvalues of the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial
$$
\chi_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2-\mathrm{tr}(A)\lambda+\det(A),
$$
where
$$
\mathrm{tr}(A)=a+d,\qquad\det(A)=ad-bc.
$$
Let me assume you know how to compute these roots. To compute an eigenvector $u_\lambda=\begin{pmatrix}x_\lambda\\ y_\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, note that $Au_\lambda=\lambda u_\lambda$ if and only if
$$
by_\lambda=(\lambda-a)x_\lambda,\qquad cx_\lambda=(\lambda-d)y_\lambda,
$$
and that these two equations are actually equivalent (this is the sign that $\lambda$ is indeed an eigenvalue), hence a first choice for $u_\lambda$ is
$$
u_\lambda=\begin{pmatrix}b\\ \lambda-a\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This choice fails if the RHS is the zero vector, that is, if $b=0$ and $\lambda=a$, then choose
$$
u_\lambda=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda-d\\ c\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The only case when both choices fail is when $A=aI$, then both eigenvalues are $a$ and every nonzero vector is an eigenvector.