# Solve first order matrix differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If I have a differential equation $ y'(t)=A y(t)$ where A is a constant square matrix that is not diagonalizable(although it is surely possible to calculate the eigenvalues) and no initial condition is given. And now I am interested in the fundamental matrix. Is there a general method to determine this matrix? I do not want to use the exponential function and the Jordan normal form, as this is quite exhausting. Maybe there is also an ansatz possible as it is for the special case, where this differential equation is equivalent to an n-th order ode. 
I saw a method where they calculated the eigenvalues of the matrix and depending on the multiplicity n of this eigenvalue they used an exponential term(with the eigenvalue) and in each component an n-th order polynomial as a possible ansatz. Though they only did this, when they were interested in a initial value problem, so with an initial condition and not for a general solution.

I was asked to deliver an example: so $y'(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} y(t)$ If somebody can construct a fundamental matrix for this system, than this should be sufficient

Comment: Do you have a specific differential equation? Maybe seeing it suggests some trick that is good for that specific one.

Comment: I will include one

Comment: I said it wrong. I meant to say that if you were interested in a specific differential equation it would be better to give it. If you are interested how to avoid in general exponential and Jordan it is not so important to give an example.

Comment: Here is a [method](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379939/considering-the-linear-system-y-ay).

Comment: The solution to $\vec{y}'_t = A \vec{y}_t$ is $y_t = e^{tA}$. Now you need to diagonalize the matrix to find what $e^{tA}$ really is.

Comment: that is the point $A$ is not necessarily diagonalizable!!!

Comment: so maybe there is somebody who knows how to calculate the fundamental matrix to the ODE that I have written down there.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I don't know whether this method also works for non-diagonalizable matrices

Comment: @Lipschitz: You need only to find the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and the corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ and then construct the general solution $y(t)=c_1v_1e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 v_2e^{\lambda_2 t}$.

Comment: But A is not diagonalizable! Does really nobody know how to do this? Maybe it has something to do with generalized eigenspaces

Comment: @Lipschitz: Do you know how to find the Eigen values and Eigen vectors? You do not need to diagonalize your matrix for this process.

Comment: yeah, well not every matrix is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have many ways to proceed and this is only a $2x2$. We can choose from:

- [*Nineteen Dubious Ways to Compute the Exponential of a
  Matrix, Twenty-Five Years Later*](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf)
- Putzer's Method 1 and Method 2
- For non-repeated eigenvalues, we can simply write:
  $$ x(t) = e^{At}x_0 = Pe^{Jt}P^{-1}x_0 = c_1v_1e^{\lambda_1 t} + \ldots + c_nv_ne^{\lambda_n t} $$
- The Direct Method for repeated eigenvalues

$$\tag 1 e^{At} = \left[I+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(A-\lambda I)^k}{k!}t^k\right]e^{\lambda t}$$

For the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$, we have:

$\det [A-\lambda I] = \det \begin{bmatrix} 3-\lambda & -4 \\ 1 & -1-\lambda \end{bmatrix} = 0 \rightarrow \lambda^2-2 \lambda+1 = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_{1,2} = 1,1$ (a double eigenvalue). From the eigenvalues, we derive the eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs:

- $\lambda_1 = 1, v_1 = (2, 1)$
- $\lambda_2 = 1, v_2 = (1, 0)$ (the second eigenvector is a generalized one)

Lets find the matrix exponential using two different methods.

**Method 1**

From $(1)$, we have:

$$e^{At} = \left[I + \dfrac{(A-\lambda I)^0}{1!}t^1 \right]e^{\lambda t} = \left[\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -4 \\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}t\right] = e^{t}\begin{bmatrix} 1+2t & -4t \\ t & 1-2t \end{bmatrix} $$

**Method 2**

Use the Laplace Transform.

$$e^{At}=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left((sI-A)^{-1}\right)=
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\begin{bmatrix}s-3 & 4 \\ -1 & s+1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\right)
= e^{t}\begin{bmatrix}1+2 t & -4 t \\ t & 1-2 t\end{bmatrix}$$

$\vdots$

**Method n**

Try other approaches discussed above!

**Update: Method n+1**

If you wanted to write $A$ using [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), we would have:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} = PJP^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$$

To write the matrix exponential for this, we take advantage of the Jordan Block and have:

$$e^{At} = e^{PJP^{-1}t} = Pe^{Jt}P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot e^{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}t} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} e^t & te^t \\ 0 & e^t\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} = e^{t}\begin{bmatrix}1+2 t & -4 t \\ t & 1-2 t\end{bmatrix}$$

Lastly, it is worth noting that sometimes the Fundamental Matrix is given as:

$$\phi(t, t_0) = \phi(t) \cdot \phi^{-1}(t_0)$$

Comment: great, that was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @Lipschitz: You are very welcome! I would certainly write out the solution for $y(t)$ using the various approaches. Glad I could help! Regards

Comment: Whoa! You went to town on this one too!!

Comment: Go take a hike, hey?! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods for determining the matrix exponential, even for a non-diagonalizable matrix. One of the easiest is via the Laplace transform. You can check that

$$\mathcal{L}(e^{tA})(s) = (sI-A)^{-1}.$$

For your example,

$$\mathcal{L}(e^{tA})(s) = \begin{bmatrix}s-3 & 4 \\ -1 & s+1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{(s-1)^2}\begin{bmatrix}s+1 & -4 \\ 1 & s-3\end{bmatrix},$$

and a (component-wise) inverse Laplace transform gives
$$
e^{tA} = \begin{bmatrix}(2t+1)e^t & -4te^t \\ te^t & -(2t-1)e^t\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Formally, this is only valid for $t>0$, but since the elements in $e^{tA}$ are holomorphic, the identity theorem for holomorphic functions shows that the equality is valid for all $t$.